# Filter list of objects, where nested collection matches an array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, icollection

I have a list of objects (`items`) which I would like to filter basis the values of a nested collection (`Features` in object `GenericItem`). As basis for the filter I have an array of int (`filter`).  My objective is to find all objects in `items` where the `Features` collection includes *at least all values* in the `filter` array.

Following many solutions provided to others on Stackoverflow I have written the below.  The problem I have is that in my Linq query (and the many variations I have tried) I always end up getting all objects in `items` where all `Features` are included in `filter`.  I understand that my lambda expression is "in the wrong order", however because I want to end up with a list of `GenericItem` I can't seem to figure out how to write my expression.

How should I write the Linq expression to get the expected result?

So in the below, when I filter for an array of `[2, 3]` my objective is to get `result` holding "Item A" and "Item B" (both have at least features 2 and 3).  Instead I get the `result` of "Item B" and "Item C" as *all* of their `Features` are included in the `filter` array.

```
public class GenericItem {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Feature> Features { get; set; }
}

public class Feature {
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

static void Main (string[] args) {

    var items = new List<GenericItem>();
    items.Add(new GenericItem() {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "Item A",
        Features = new Collection<Feature>() { 
            new Feature() {Id = 1},      
            new Feature() {Id = 2},      
            new Feature() {Id = 3}
        }      
    });
    items.Add(new GenericItem() {
        Id = 2,
        Name = "Item B",
        Features = new Collection<Feature>() {     
            new Feature() {Id = 2},      
            new Feature() {Id = 3}
        }      
    });
    items.Add(new GenericItem() {
        Id = 3,
        Name = "Item C",
        Features = new Collection<Feature>() {    
            new Feature() {Id = 3}
        }
    });

    int[] filter = new int[] {2, 3};

    var resultAll = items.Where(i => i.Features.All(f => filter.Contains(f.Id)));

    foreach (GenericItem I in resultAll)
        System.Console.WriteLine(I.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply `All` to the `filter` collection instead of the `i.Features`:

```
var resultAll = items.Where(i => filter.All(x => i.Features.Any(f => x == f.Id)));
```

Comment: Thank you for your very quick solution!